# Not able to boot into windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I installed ubuntu along side my windows 10, and it is booting directly to windows. So i ran `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`. Then grub menu showed up with 3 options

1. ubuntu
2. ubuntu advanced options
3. Windows Boot manager

Now I'm able to select ubuntu but selecting windows boot manager is bringing me back to the grub menu itself. I am not able to goto windows.

I ran boot repair in ubuntu and same problems persists and here is the link to its report https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SPJZrDFkJS/.

I tried the solution given in [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix) , then also same problem - clicking on Windows(UEFI) in grub menu is bringing me back to the grub menu itself.